# Access buttons with loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make my 9 buttons back color red, so I tried to use a loop method to make them colorful one by one and I also used a sleep function to make delay between them. Here is my code:

```
// Random R = new Random();
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
{
    button(i).BackColor = Color.red;
    thread.Sleep(2000); // 2 seconds
}
```

I also used a Random method which is now disabled and I want it, to randomly make buttons colorful but I don't know how to do it.

My code is also incorrect because " button(i) " is not acceptable and I have no idea how to use i for numbering the buttons.

for example: button1 ... button2 ... button3 ... etc

Comment: Please post the code for where/how you are creating the buttons.  You need to use the objects name/ID to reference it.

Comment: You need to create an array of buttons. Set each element of the array to one of your named buttons then you can use a loop and the array indexer as array[i]. Anyway, if you have a problem like this I really suggest you to stop for a moment and use some resource to cover the basic steps in C# language

Comment: Are all of those buttons located inside the same control (panel, groupbox, etc)?

Comment: Running `thread.Sleep(2000)` on the main thread (where UI is drawn) is a really bad idea. You want this code to run async to maintain UI response while running.

Comment: @Steve Yes, thanks for the idea. Arrays will do the job.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Yes, I read a lot about how to make breaks in C# and buy some time for delays or other purposes. I used the easiest way but I don't know how to do it effectively.

Comment: Use `Task` and the methods under it with the `async/await` keywords to make responsive asynchronous code. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want this

[image: fig1]

collect the buttons in an array  `buttons` and use this code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static Random rng = new Random();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public async Task ColorButtons(Color color)
    {
        var buttons = new Button[] {
            button1, button2, button3,
            button4, button5, button6,
            button7, button8, button9 };

        void Swap(ref Button item1, ref Button item2)
        {
            Button temp = item2;
            item2 = item1;
            item1 = temp;
        }

        // shuffle order
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < buttons.Length; j++)
            {
                if (rng.NextDouble()<0.5)
                {
                    Swap(ref buttons[i], ref buttons[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        // color buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].BackColor = color;
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }

    }

    private async void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await ColorButtons(Color.Red);
    }

    private async void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await ColorButtons(Color.Blue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few assumptions based on your code sample, if any of these assumptions are incorrect you will need to update the appropriate variable(s)

- I'm assuming your buttons are named Button1, Button2, Button3, etc
- I'm assuming you're using WinForms and the form is named Form1
- I'm assuming you have 9 buttons that you would like to update

  ```
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
    {
        ((Button) Form1.Controls.Find("Button" + i, true)[0]).BackColor = Color.Red;
        thread.Sleep(2000); // 2 seconds
    }
  ```

This example uses [ControlCollection.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=net-5.0) to find each Button based on the Name property of the control itself.

Comment: It is somehow a little complicated but I thanks for the idea, ControlCollection.Find. I learned something new.